# GWT: How to dynamically load a new image?

Tags: gwt

I want to fetch an image from a remote server (not my app's server, but I don't think that matters) and display it in an existing Image widget. The existing widget displays its original content, from a ClientBundle ImageResource , OK.

In UiBinder template:

```
<g:Image ui:field='myImage' resource='{res.anImage}'/>
```

In code:

```
@UiField Image      myImage;
...
int width = Window.getClientWidth();
int height = Window.getClientHeight();
String url = ...;

myImage.addErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
    public void onError(ErrorEvent event) {
        Window.alert("Error getting image data: " + event);
    }
  });
myImage.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {
    public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
        Window.alert("LoadEvent: " + event);
    }
  });
myImage.setUrlAndVisibleRect(url, 0, 0, width, height);
```

As far as I can tell setUrlAndVisibleRect is a no-op. FireBug reports no network activity -- no request to the server specified by the URL. What am I overlooking? In my extended thrashing about trying to get this working I have inferred that it **may** have something to do with myImage not being "logically attached", but I'm not entirely sure what that means and I've no idea how to correct it if that is the problem.

EDIT with SUMMARY of SOLUTION:
My initial hunch was right. Because I had chosen to implement the image code within a second pseudo-widget (`...extends Composite`) that shared my UiBinder template with the main pseudo-widget that implements most of my app's UI, I got into trouble. I neglected to add this second pseudo-widget to the RootPanel as is normally done in the class that implements EntryPoint. This left my Image widget unattached to the widget chain, because its parent, the second pseudo-widget, was unattached. And an Image widget must be attached to work. What I ended up doing is moving the Image code back into my main app/GUI class, i.e., into the first and now only pseudo-widget and abandoning the special class for the Image code. I did that because it's simpler and the Image code turns out not to be as long as I had originally thought.

Comment: Where are you calling the `setUrlAndVisibleRect`? Also why are you using the height/width of the whole window? In such cases the simpler `setUrl()` should do the job.

Comment: I'm calling setUrlAndVisibleRect from a method in a `class MyImage extends Composite` which I created so that its code could share my UiBinder template via a @UiTemplate annotation. And whole window rather than just setUrl both to get the clipping feature of the Image widget and because the new image is larger than the window and I want the whole window to be the "viewport".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding  image to the DOM is little tricky,the below code which supports all the browsers(`setVisibility` trick added to support IE also,as It has a different way to image rendering).

I did'nt use `setUrlAndVisibleRect` before and AFAIK,Image must render to the DOM inorder to resize it.Just try the below codes.

```
 image.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
              //Do your operations on image .//resize ..etc
             image.getElement().getStyle().setVisibility
                                          (Style.Visibility.Visible); 
                      }
                 });

    image.getElement().getStyle().setVisibility(Style.Visibility.HIDDEN); 
    RootPanel.get().add(image);
    image.setUrl(url);
```

Comment: I am about to try your suggestion and I will report a result. Meanwhile, do you know if recent versions -- 9, 10 -- of IE require the `setVisibility` trick? Right now the Image widget is in a hidden `<div ...>`which I make visible after calling `setUrlAndVisibleRect`.

Comment: Success! Thanks! FWIW... Originally I had added the Image to the HTMLPanel that is at the top of my UiBinder rather than to the RootPanel because I mistakenly assumed that the HTMLPanel was logically attached to the RootPanel after the initial `RootPanel.get().add(new Gui())` in my EntryPoint class's onModuleLoad.

Comment: @brec :) glad to help you.happens to every programmer :)

Comment: P.S. I noticed that if I did a myImage.setVisibleRect(...) within onLoad then onload is called twice. So I took that out and am calling myImage.setUrlAndVisibleRect rather than setUrl.

Comment: Oops..seems like setUrlAndVisble calling  onload method...i did'nt check the implementation ..

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ClientBundle ImageResource` which is ***compile time***. You **cannot** change it unless you replace the new image with exact name in the exact position of prev one. One of the possible hack which is possible is, place the image in a div with its ID set ( `getElement().setId("your ID")` ). Once you get you **new image** you use [RootPanel.get("Your Id")](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RootPanel.html#get%28java.lang.String%29) and do your job.

Comment: Originally I had only `g:Image ui:field='myImage'/>`, but I thought in my thrashing around that maybe setUrlAndVisibleRect needed something to replace so I put in the `resource=`. ... I think RootPanel.get() and RootPanel.get("My Id") would in this case return the same thing, but, sorry, I don't know what you want me to do with the RootPanel ("do [my] job").